# Following a tutorial resulted in broken MAMP installation

Tags: php, macos, mamp

Hooked up MAMP on my Macbook (OSX) a month ago and everything was fine.  Then I followed a bogus tutorial on how to debug PHP in Eclipse (didn't work), and now my php files open with:

file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/

instead of:

http://localhost:8888/

which displays code only now.  PHP files can be viewed on the server if I append the filename to the localhost url in the browser, but can anyone tell me how to configure PHP/MAMP properly?  I'm new at this stuff and tried to fix this on my own, but no dice =/

Comment: What's broken? `file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/foo.php` can't work, but `http://localhost:8888/foo.php` should.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your work will probably be reconfiguring /etc/apache2/httdp.conf.
Configuring Apache is a vast topic, you might be better off using google to find a good tutorial.
At the least, you'll need a handler eg.:

```
# PHP file handlers.
<IfModule php5_module>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

        <IfModule dir_module>
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You've likely pinned the issue, but you shouldn't point to the built-in Apache configuration. He's using MAMP.

Comment: yea http://localhost:8888/myfilename.php displays the file correctly, but it's not the default display settings for php.  before this crap happened, php files would open with mamp/apache by default.  but now even if i go into the mamp/htdocs folder, it doesn't use the server

Comment: thanks guys for the tips, still having issues though.  any general stuff i should look into?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out!  if anyone's having the same problem...

go here:
http://sawmac.com/mamp/
to set up mamp properly

and here:
http://sawmac.com/mamp/virtual/
to correctly setup the virtual hosts on your mac

p.s.
if you screwed up mamp's apache settings like i did, completely remove the program and reinstall it before doing the above.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in a non-MAMP solution, here's a set of instructions that uses OSX Mountain Lion's native Apache2 and XDebug together with MacGDBp and a Safari extension called XDebug Helper. http://dokimay.com/index.php/mac-osx/56-configuring-xdebug-on-osx-mountain-lion